# Adding shared library to websphere server application in eclipse luna

Tags: eclipse, server, websphere

I'm trying to add a shared library to a local Websphere server application using the Admin Console in Eclipse Luna.

I created the shared library in the Environment -> Shared Libraries section. I then go the Application -> WebSphere enterprise applications -> EDSServices -> Shared library references section. I select the application and click the Reference shared libraries button to get to the Shared Library Mapping screen. On that screen, I select the shared library in the Available window and hit the right arrow button. The screen blinks and the library un-highlights in the Available window, but does not show up in the Selected window.

[screenshot of Admin Console Shared Library Mapping page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zl7rB.jpg)

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by using Chrome to access the local server admin console instead of getting to the admin console through eclipse itself. Using Chrome, the shared library information moved when selected like it was supposed to.